# Loop with Lavaan in R couldn't find the variable

Tags: r, loops, r-lavaan

I was running the following code so that my Lavaan Model can test different predictors. However, the error says it couldn't find my "predictor". I need to keep that "paste" row so that I can specify whether it is a ".x" or ".y" variable. I feel it's a simple question. Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

```
gender_thermometer.x <-sample(0:10, 1000, rep = TRUE)
gender_thermometer.y <-sample(0:10, 1000, rep = TRUE)
COVID_threat.x <-sample(0:10, 1000, rep = TRUE)
COVID_threat.y <-sample(0:10, 1000, rep = TRUE)
d_exhaustion.x <-sample(0:10, 1000, rep = TRUE)
d_relaxation.x <-sample(0:10, 1000, rep = TRUE)
d_not_sharing_negative.x <-sample(0:1, 1000, rep = TRUE)
Couple_ID <-sample(0:100, 1000, rep = TRUE)
data_wide<-data.frame(gender_thermometer.x,gender_thermometer.y,COVID_threat.x,COVID_threat.y,
                      d_exhaustion.x,d_relaxation.x,d_not_sharing_negative.x,Couple_ID)

library(lavaan)
models <- list()

for (i in c( "gender_thermometer","COVID_threat")) {
  
  print(paste0("###################:",i))
  predictor= paste(i,".y",sep = "")
  
  model[[i]] <- '
    level: 1
        d_exhaustion.x ~ b1*d_relaxation.x + c1*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_relaxation.x ~ a1*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_not_sharing_negative.x~f1*predictor
        indirect1:=f1*a1*b1
        indirect11:=f1*c1
    level: 2
        d_exhaustion.x ~ b2*d_relaxation.x + c2*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_relaxation.x ~ a2*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_not_sharing_negative.x~f2*predictor
        indirect2:=f2*a2*b2
        indirect22:=f2*c2
        
'
  
  fit[[i]] <- sem(model = model[[i]], data = data_wide, cluster = "Couple_ID")
  print(summary(fit[[i]]))
}
```

> Error in lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, cluster = cluster,  :
> lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: predictor

Answer (score 0):

R string formatting requires interpolation handlers like `sprintf` or `paste` like you do in assigning `predictor`. Currently, the model string takes literal *predictor* and not its underlying value.

So, consider string formatting such as with [**`sprintf`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf) (wrapper to C function):

```r
vars <- c("gender_thermometer", "COVID_threat")
models <- vector(mode="list", length=length(vars))

for (i in seq_along(vars)) {  
  print(paste0("###################:", vars[[i]]))
  predictor <- paste0(vars[[i]], ".y")
  
  # STRING WITH %1$s PLACEHOLDERS
  model_string <- '
    level: 1
        d_exhaustion.x ~ b1*d_relaxation.x + c1*d_not_sharing_negative.x + %1$s
        d_relaxation.x ~ a1*d_not_sharing_negative.x + %1$s
        d_not_sharing_negative.x~f1*%1$s
        indirect1:=f1*a1*b1
        indirect11:=f1*c1
    level: 2
        d_exhaustion.x ~ b2*d_relaxation.x + c2*d_not_sharing_negative.x + %1$s
        d_relaxation.x ~ a2*d_not_sharing_negative.x + %1$s
        d_not_sharing_negative.x~f2*%1$s
        indirect2:=f2*a2*b2
        indirect22:=f2*c2
  '
  
  # FORMAT STRING WITH VALUE
  models[[i]] <- sprintf(model_string, predictor)
  cat(models[[i]])

  fit[[i]] <- sem(model = models[[i]], data = data_wide, cluster = "Couple_ID")

  print(summary(fit[[i]]))
}
```

Alternatively with `gsub`, replacing literal *predictor* with variable value:

```r
model_string <- '
    level: 1
        d_exhaustion.x ~ b1*d_relaxation.x + c1*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_relaxation.x ~ a1*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_not_sharing_negative.x~f1*predictor
        indirect1:=f1*a1*b1
        indirect11:=f1*c1
    level: 2
        d_exhaustion.x ~ b2*d_relaxation.x + c2*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_relaxation.x ~ a2*d_not_sharing_negative.x + predictor
        d_not_sharing_negative.x~f2*predictor
        indirect2:=f2*a2*b2
        indirect22:=f2*c2
'

models[[i]] <- gsub("predictor", predictor, model_string)
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait, Thanks for your answer. I followed your suggestion. However, I still got errors, same for both approaches.  > Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, value = sem(model = model[[i]], data = data_wide,  : 
  [[<- defined for objects of type "S4" only for subclasses of environment

Comment: If you hard code the variables such as `gender_thermometer.y` (replacing *predictor*) and run the model outside the loop, do you receive the same error? I am not familiar with `lavaan` with that very different model formula.

Comment: That's a good idea. I tested. I didn't encounter the error if I hard-coded the variables. So it only happened when I used Loop.

Comment: Very strange. Are you running this loop beyond the two variables you post here? Maybe one of the variables do not work. What is the last `print` statement before error?

Comment: No. I was only running the two variables. Good question. Before the error, it only printed out "[1] "###################:gender_thermometer""

Comment: I have edited my post to be clear on implementation and also adjusted list index to integer. Can you edit your post with hard-coded, non-loop version that runs without error? I want to compare for any subtle difference. These methods, `sprintf` and `gsub`, should return *exactly* a character equivalent to hard-coded version. In fact, run `cat(model[[i]])`, to confirm.